# how to configure keyboard shortcuts in latest chrome (114.0.5735.198 version) such as: "go to last tab"

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to understand how can I customize keyboard shortcuts in chrome(version 114.0.5735.198), specifically "go to last active tab" short cut.

Right now the only thing I can do is the cumbersome **shift+command+a** shortcut the opens a new menu which from there I can go to latest active tabs... but again its cumbersone

I have the latest Ventura maco version

thanks!